# Bootstrap Modal On this template

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I used this template http://www.templatemo.com/tm-409-travel 
But, Why I can'not use modal bootstrap. Excample on my homepage. You can see on my site at: [shakiragrafika.com/public](http://shakiragrafika.com/public)

The modal button is "View Detail", you can click it.!
Why My Modal bootstrap Can not show..? 
Whats wrong the code on this template..?

Could you track what wrong..?

thanks..

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have inspected the code, the div "#myModalInput" has been provided as the target but it has not been defined any where in the code. Is it present somewhere else? Because in your code there is clearly not present. Only a commented portion could be seen. Please check below:

[image: The Inspected Code]